# playbook vs blackberry api

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

what is the difference between blackberry smartphone sdk and blackberry playbook sdk?
can a blackberry phone application work on a blackberry playbook?

Comment: Just guessing, but going to assume no. Playbook has entire new OS under the hood based on QNX. Otherwise the Playbook's appworld would have most anything in BBAppWorld in it already

Comment: application will work in both?

Answer (score 6):

It depends.  If your BB smartphone app is developed using the WebWorks SDK, then it is possible to run on both smartphone and playbook.  If your BB smartphone app is developed using Java, then no it will not run on the playbook.

See [RIM's developer site for the Playbook](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/).

Answer (score 2):

A blackberry phone (and Android) applications will work on a blackberry playbook - when RIM releases [the Java SDKs](http://press.rim.com/release.jsp?id=4935) for Playbook (not available at Playbook release date)

Answer (score 1):

We're all waiting for the Android Player to be released by RIM. This would allow Android apps to run on a PlayBook. There isn't a "native" SDK available.

This was demo'ed at BlackBerry World Orlando May 2011. See http://blogs.blackberry.com/2011/05/blackberry-playbook-android-app-player-demo-video/ for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

playbook is run on the QNX OS and blackberry smartphone have their on OS.both are totaly differnet.with the help of Blackberry Brige you can run your blackberry application to playbook.they told that they will support java on playbook but still no update is comming in that.

Answer (score 0):

The PlayBook currently has 3 APIs: WebWorks, AIR, and native C++.

Currently the C++ api is not released but I have heard that there are leaks of it's functionality.

A WebWorks app created for the BlackBerry can be ported the PlayBook, but will probably require some changes to the resolution and UI so that it fits well on the new resolution. It also works PlayBook to BlackBerry.

An AIR app cannot be moved to a BlackBerry.

When RIM moves away from the Legacy OS on the BlackBerry it will be possible to run an AIR app on a BlackBerry as they BlackBerry and the PlayBook will be running the same Operating System.